# setEnabled not working in some menus in Qt 5.4.1?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, contextmenu, qt-creator, menubar

This is really strange situation I am facing here, I tried to solve it by myself by failed. Tried google, but couldn't find the issue I am facing here.
I have created 5 menus, File, Edit, View, Render, and Windows.

There are some actions in View menu such as "Copy Part(s)" and "Paste Part(s)", etc.

When I triggered to "Copy Part(s)" action, then "Paste Part(s)" should be enabled. So I call pasteShellsAct->setEnabled(true) in copyShellsAct_cb() Slot. It never worked/enabled. But if I call pasteShellsAct->setEnabled(true) in any other menu's action's Slot it works fine. For example I call pasteShellsAct->setEnabled(true) in File's action's Slot open(), or Render's action's Slot on3D(), it works fine.

What I am thinking is, there can be a conflict between Slots of different actions? May be I am missing something? I am not sure. Why this is happening?

here is some code...

```
    copyShellsAct = new QAction(tr("Copy Part(s)"), this);
    copyShellsAct->setEnabled(true);
    connect(copyShellsAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(copyShellsAct_cb()));

    pasteShellsAct = new QAction(tr("Paste Part(s)"), this);
    pasteShellsAct->setEnabled(false);
    connect(pasteShellsAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(pasteShellsAct_cb()));

void FurApp::fvkQtMenu::copyShellsAct_cb()
{
    // Output of TRUE and FALSE works fine. But action doesn't get Enabled on in View menu. Other menus are working fine. 
    if(pasteShellsAct->isEnabled())
        qDebug() << "TRUE";
    else
        qDebug() << "FALSE";

    pasteShellsAct->setEnabled(true);
}

void FurApp::fvkQtMenu::pasteShellsAct_cb()
{
    pasteShellsAct->setEnabled(false);
}
```

Any idea? I am sure I am missing something but what?

I am using Qt 5.4.1 with VS2010 under Windows 8.1.
Thanks.

Comment: can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which exhibits the problem you are describing?

Comment: It looks good.. I guess the first part of initialization is done in MainWindow constructor (or whatever you call that class).. I agree with that MCVE - you may find out that the problem is totally at different part of your code which we cannot see from code you provided. You can just search the code if you do not accidently set `pasteShellsAct->setEnabled(false);` somewhere in your code..

Comment: @otopolsky thanks, yes that is the issue, I have tried everything, but couldn't find the issue. I have one class in which I am creating all the menus and actions and that class inherits from QObject. I don't see any other issue in my software but the only View Menu actions do not Enable or Disable in run time. Other menu actions working fine. Thanks for the advice, let me check again by searching or this specific action.

Comment: btw, you can just write "qDebug() << pasteShellsAct->isEnabled();" instead of using if (...) ...

Comment: Menus are really disabled, or they are only looks like disabled? I fixed such bug some days ago.

Comment: @SaZ I think its a bug in Qt, I notices that some other people also described the same kind of situation. 
Its stays disabled, whatever I do, but works fine with other menus, Submenus's actions and some group actions do not change their state to Enabled. So should I update the Qt? I think its not released yet. I am using 5.4.1\

Comment: I couldn't help with debug without an sscce. Anyway, you may create a bugreport too.